Suppress shell output of vscode on poweshell in windows terminal
When I start vscode from powershell command line I get:
PS C:\Applications> Code
PS C:\Applications>
[main 2024-07-24T14:05:08.273Z] update#setState disabled
[main 2024-07-24T14:05:08.274Z] update#ctor - updates are disabled by user preference
[17084:0724/170510.787:ERROR:electron_api_app.cc(1268)] Failed to begin Jump List transaction.
[main 2024-07-24T14:05:10.780Z] updateWindowsJumpList#setJumpList unexpected result: error

Namely the log of vscode is shown in the terminal.
Is there a way to prevent it?
Disconnect the vscode process from the processed it was launched (Though inherit all system variables)?
Is there a general way to do so?

I don't get any output when launching from command line.  I wonder if you have an extension that has a log level set too high, or that is just too chatty?  Maybe try code --log off?  Although that might have further implications than what you are after.

I only have the Python extensions: MS Python, MS Pylance, MS Jupyter.

Are you by any chance launching Code.exe instead of code.cmd? Try typing code.cmd instead

@Destroy666, I do launch Code.exe. I haven't seen code.cmd. Where is that?

The proper way to launch VSCode on Windows in CLI is with code.cmd. You are apparently running Code.exe for whatever reason.
code.cmd is under normal circumstances (default installation) in %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd and in path, unlike Code.exe, so that you can just use code.
See also documentation
